# How to change "input file" storage location in customer account edit form

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, media, file-upload

I have added a customer attribute called "My File". It gets added in customer account edit form. By default, the selected file(My File) is saved under "pub/media/customer" directory. In my case, I want to save those files alone under "pub/media/my_files". How to achieve it? Please help me!

Creating attributes in InstallData.php

```
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Customer Attribute setup factory
     *
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Customer Attribute setup factory
     *
     * @var ProductMetadataInterface
     */
    private $productMetadataInterface;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     * @param ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadataInterface
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadataInterface)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->productMetadataInterface = $productMetadataInterface;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


            $attributeList['my_file'] = [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'My file',
                'input' => 'file',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 150,
                'position' => 150,
                'system' => 0,
                'validate_rules' => '{"max_file_size":1048576,"file_extensions":"pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,PDF,JPG,PNG,JPEG"}'
            ];

        $attributeList['my_file_link'] = [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'My File Link',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 160,
            'position' => 160,
            'system' => 0
        ];


        foreach ($attributeList as $key => $value) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key, $value);

            //add attribute to attribute set
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key)
                            ->addData(
                                [
                                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer']
                                ]
                            );

            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use any extension ? If not then share your code where you wrote to save attribute value.

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can modiy code as per you need. I suggest you to observe `customer_register_success` event. More about observers [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-events-observers/).

```
        $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'my_file']);
        //Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf']);
        $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
        // Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('your preferable directory under media');
        $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

        $document = $result['file'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the support! But if we use, customer_register_success event, it gets triggered after saving the customer details right? In this scenario, already the file gets uploaded in the customer folder, right?

Comment: I dont think so. In observer you can change that behaviour.